# Regex to grab content using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Here is the text that needs to be preg_matched.

```
/* * product 2: * catalogServiceType = 2 * catalogCacheType = 1 * catalog2RemoteCacheActive = false */ var objProduct881705 = new ProductStyle("2","881705","","4149367","247",false,false,false,false,'','',"35401",false,'$79.50',true,false,false,false,0,false,true,false,true,99,5,"First content that needs to be matched",'Color',"","Machine.","","false","false","false",0,0,"C1","1","",true);obj={'S':'http://domainname.com/mini/image.jpg', 'L':'http://domainname.com/main/image.jpg'};
```

I would like to be able to grab the following from the text above:

```
1. First content that needs to be matched
2. http://domainname.com/main/image.jpg
```

How do you propose I can do this?

Comment: This is not clear. Do you have the above code (you designated it as text) in a string? What do you need to match?

Comment: The above that you converted into "code" view was the text that was returned to me in a string form.  I need to get the text "First content that needs to be matched" and "http://domainname.com/main/image.jpg" from the string.

Comment: Would the strings always be "First content that needs to be matched"? If not, specify precisely the rule to extract the text. Like would it always be the 25th argument to `new ProductStyle()`. Wait! "First content that needs to be matched" doesn't even exist in the string you have provided. Instead, it is: "\"First content that needs to be \" +\n  \"matched\"".

Comment: @Susan - see the rolled back version above.  It will always be string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
preg_match('/new ProductStyle\(([^\)]+)\)/', $html, $matches);
$jsonValues = '[' . $matches[1] . ']';
$jsonValues = preg_replace_callback("/(?<=,)'(.*?)'(?=,)/", create_function(
      '$matches',
      'return \'"\' . addslashes(strip_tags($matches[1])) . \'"\';'
    ), $jsonValues);
$values = json_decode($jsonValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex newbie here, got something with that:

```
/\((.+?,){25}\"(.+?)\".+?'L':'(.+?)'/
```